# Add a textbox against a radio button to BIRT report parameters window

Tags: birt

In BIRT, the report parameters window that pops up for user input ,I am taking two radio buttons. For the first radio button ,I am giving 'ALL' to select all office codes.
For the second radio button , I want to add a text box where the user can give one particular office code as input.

I would like to know how to add a text box against a radio button.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible to do as you ask, but it would require creating a custom parameter.  This is an easier solution for what I imagine is what you are trying to do.

The easier solution use a single text box in your parameter, set the default value to "All" and SQL code in your query similar to this.

```
 where CONTCTSM1.OPERATOR_ID = ?
    or
        ('All' = ? 
        and
        CONTCTSM1.ACTIVE = 'f' )
```

With this code if a specific value is given it returns results for that one parameter.  If the Value is left as All, then it returns all values where CONTCTSM1.ACTIVE = 'f'